# POST to WCF from Fiddler succeeds but passes null values

Tags: wcf, json, fiddler

I've followed [this video series on WCF](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Hosting-WCF-Services-in-IIS/) and have the demo working.  It involves building a WCF service that manages student evaluation forms, and implements CRUD operations to operate on a list of those evaluations.  I've modified my code a little according to [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx) so it will return JSON results to a browser or Fiddler request.  My goal is to figure out how to use the service by building my own requests in Fiddler, and then use that format to consume the service from an app on a mobile device.

I'm having trouble using the `SubmitEval` method (save an evaluation) from Fiddler.  The call works, but all the fields of `Eval` are null (or default) except `Id`, which is set in the service itself.

Here is my `Eval` declaration (using properties instead of fields as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058942/how-to-call-wcf-restful-service-from-fiddler-by-json-request)):

```
[DataContract]
public class Eval //Models an evaluation
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Submitter { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime TimeSubmitted { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the relevant part of `IEvalService`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEvalService
{
 ...
   [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "eval")]
    void SubmitEval(Eval eval);
}
```

And `EvalService`:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
class EvalService : IEvalService
{
...
  public void SubmitEval(Eval eval)
    {
        eval.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Received eval");
        evals.Add(eval);
    }
}
```

In Fiddler's Request Builder, I set the Method to POST and the address to `http://localhost:49444/EvalServiceSite/Eval.svc/eval`.  I added the header `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` to the default headers.  The request body is:

```
{"eval":{"Comment":"testComment222","Id":"doesntMatter", 
  "Submitter":"Tom","TimeSubmitted":"11/10/2011 4:00 PM"}}
```

The response I get from sending that request is `200`, but when I then look at the Evals that have been saved, the one I just added has a valid `Id`, but `Comment` and `Submitter` are both null, and `TimeSubmitted` is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`.

It seems like WCF is getting the request, but is not deserializing the object correctly.  But if that's the case, I don't know why it's not throwing some sort of exception.  Does it look like I'm doing this right, or am I missing something?

UPDATE: Here is the endpoint declaration in App.config:

```
 <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"
   contract="EvalServiceLibrary.IEvalService" />
```

And the endpoint behavior referred to:

```
<behavior name="webHttp">
  <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
</behavior>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default body style in the `WebInvoke` attribute is Bare, meaning that the object should be sent without a wrapper containing the object name:

```
{"Comment":"testComment222",
 "Id":"doesntMatter",
 "Submitter":"Tom",
 "TimeSubmitted":"11/10/2011 4:00 PM"}
```

Or you can set the request body style to `Wrapped`, and that would make the input require the wrapping `{"eval"...}` object:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
   ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
   UriTemplate = "eval",
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)] // or .Wrapped
void SubmitEval(Eval eval);
```

**Update**: there's another problem in your code, since you're using `DateTime`, and the format expected by the WCF serializer for dates in JSON is something like `\/Date(1234567890)\/`. You can change your class to support the format you have by following the logic described at [MSDN Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/09/06/wcf-extensibility-serialization-callbacks.aspx) (fine-grained control of serialization format for primitives), and shown in the code below.

```
public class StackOverflow_8086483
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Eval //Models an evaluation
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Submitter { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "TimeSubmitted")]
        private string timeSubmitted;

        public DateTime TimeSubmitted { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Eval[Id={0},Submitter={1},Comment={2},TimeSubmitted={3}]", Id, Submitter, Comment, TimeSubmitted);
        }

        [OnSerializing]
        void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
        {
            this.timeSubmitted = this.TimeSubmitted.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        [OnDeserialized]
        void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
        {
            DateTime value;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(this.timeSubmitted, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out value))
            {
                this.TimeSubmitted = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IEvalService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "eval",
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        void SubmitEval(Eval eval);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    class EvalService : IEvalService
    {
        public void SubmitEval(Eval eval)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received eval: {0}", eval);
        }
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(EvalService), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        string data = "{\"eval\":{\"Comment\":\"testComment222\",\"Id\":\"doesntMatter\", \"Submitter\":\"Tom\",\"TimeSubmitted\":\"11/10/2011 4:00 PM\"}}";
        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        c.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        c.UploadData(baseAddress + "/eval", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Http 400, to be exact.  The error message says "The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details."

Comment: It's because the DateTime in your code wasn't in the expected format. I've updated the answer with a solution for that as well.

Comment: That did it!  I expected it to parse a DateTime better because I've worked with web services before, and those were find with the usual format.

Comment: This is a common complaint with WCF. On 4.5 they fixed it so you can change the date time format

Answer (score 0):

For POST you need to use  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare  NOT
       WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate = "eval",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    void SubmitEval(Eval eval);
```