# WebAPI model is null using FromBodyAttribute when posting using Fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, fiddler

Hello All one more post request being null problem. I referred to all the posts regarding the same which made it more confusing.

My problem is below I have an Entity Class

```
public class ProductEntity
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

and the controller class

```
// POST api/product
public int Post([FromBody]ProductEntity productEntity)
{
    return _productServices.CreateProduct(productEntity);
}
```

I am using fiddler with these options as shown in the below picture

[image: Fiddler Options]

After trying an attempt of post from the fiddler I always get null value.

[image: post from fiddler]

I followed a post and as per the description because Product is a complex type I should not use `FromBody` attribute , but irrespective of this I am unable to get the object instead only null is getting passed.

I even followed the msdn link for parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api  but got confused. Please let me know what is that I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct from what I can tell, but what you are trying to send in fiddler composer is not well formed JSON so your model is not being parsed. Hence the null value.

This is what you are trying to send based on your attached image

```
{
"ProductId":8
"ProductName":"MobilePhone"
}
```

Notice you are missing a comma `,` after the `"ProductId":8`

Here is what you should be sending

```
{
"ProductId":8,
"ProductName":"MobilePhone"
}
```

Comment: spot on !! I wasted over 2 to 3 hours for this !! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeded in sending a POST with fiddler - I needed to put

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

in the request header and add a = before the JSON statement:

```
={"Name":"Turbo Tina","Email":"na@Turbo.Tina"}
```

I was inspired by this post about WCF and Fiddler: [POST to WCF from Fiddler succeeds but passes null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086483/post-to-wcf-from-fiddler-succeeds-but-passes-null-values)

If I instead of the "simple" type string expects a JObject in the method:

```
  public dynamic Post([FromBody]JObject value)
```

I can use

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

and remove the = before the JSON statement.