# POST Request in Fiddler success but passes null values

Tags: json, api, rest, wcf

When i tried to test WCF Services, strangely its returning Success but keep passes null values.

Take a look at this:

[image]

In fiddler, it's like this

[image]

i have been read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086483/post-to-wcf-from-fiddler-succeeds-but-passes-null-values) post but still can't figure out what's the problem in my case. Thanks

Comment: What is the contract for your WCF service?

Comment: @DingPeng: Here is the contract 
[OperationContract]
        `[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "/UpdateWOAssignment")]`

Comment: Does the parameter in the UpdateWOAssignment method use the DataContract feature?

Comment: WCF uses DataContract to serialize data. If DataContract is not used, the problem you mentioned may occur.

Comment: @DingPeng ah got it. I remove [Data Contract] which i found inside my class. Its solve my problem. 
Can you give an answer to my question. I ll mark your answer. Thanks

Comment: I have posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF uses DataContract to serialize data. If DataContract is not used, the problem you mentioned may occur.